# Putting a table result as a text column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, the first one is a table of companies, and the second one is a table of shareholders we could say. The shareholder table can have upwards of a thousand shareholders.

I need to make a view/another table which has every shareholder name on a single text column along with the unique identifier of the company, the name and "fake" name of the company.

Table 1 Company:

```
ID CompanyID Name FantasyName
1          1  A    Company 1
2          2  B    Company 2 
3          3  C    Company 3
4          4  D    Company 4
5          5  E    Company 5
6          6  F    Company 6
7          7  G    Company 7
```

Table 2 Shareholders:

```
ID CompanyID Name
 1         1 John 1
 2         1 Peter 2
 3         1 Gabriel Li
 4         2 Raphael 3
 5         2 Anderson 4
 6         2 Michael 6
 7         2 Angelina Jo
 8         3 John 8
 9         4 Beatrice
10         4 Scarlet
11         5 Scarlet
12         5 Logan
13         5 John 1
```

I tried to do this via Linq through C# but it hasn't been fast enough for my purpose, this table contains upwards of millions of companies.

The end result would look like this:

Table 3 Company and Shareholders:

```
ID CompanyID Name FantasyName Shareholders
1          1  A    Company 1  John 1,Peter 2,Gabriel Li
2          2  B    Company 2  Raphael 3, Anderson 4,Michael 6,Angelina Jo
3          3  C    Company 3  John 8
4          4  D    Company 4  Beatrice,Scarlet
5          5  E    Company 5  Scarlet,Logan,John 1
...
```

All shareholders in a single TEXT field, with the company info accompanying it.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Huh I need to use this with Manticore search, so this table would be made to create that indexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT
    c.ID,
    c.CompanyID,
    c.Name,
    c.FantasyName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.Name) Shareholders
FROM 
    Company c
    INNER JOIN Shareholders s ON s.CompanyID = c.CompanyID 
GROUP BY
    c.ID,
    c.CompanyID,
    c.Name,
    c.FantasyName
```

Comment: @LeviBarrocas: does this properly answers your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay and indeed it does!